# Importing a folder-tree of html files into mediawiki?

Tags: html, mediawiki, wiki

Let's say we have a tree of several nested folders and within each of them there are several simple HTML files.

Is there a way to import this structure into a media-wiki website?  (or alternatively, to add to these HTML files a wiki-like feature)?

I am not sure what tools can do such a task or where to ask about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a HTML to wikitext converter (there are several, e. g. the [HTML::WikiConverter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-WikiConverter/) Perl module, or [this web service](https://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/), or [this xsl file](http://mozile.mozdev.org/0.8/demos/html2wiki.xsl)) and some bot framework to automate it (the most mature one is [pywikipediabot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikipediabot)).